# Correctness of algorithm to find maximum in array

Tags: algorithms, arrays, correctness-proof

I want to show correctness of "Algorithm to find maximum element in array" using induction and contradiction.

```
ans=-infinity
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    ans= max(ans, A[i])
```

where A[0:n-1] is array and max is the function to return maximum of its two arguments.

What I am doing:

Base case: `i=0, ans= max(-infinity,A[0])=A[0],` as only one element has been processsed, it is maximum.

Induction Hypothesis: `i=k<n-1`, assume the algorithm correctly find maximum upto k iterations.

Inductive Step: `i=k+1`, let `ans_{i}` denote maximum element obtained by algorithm upto i steps and let `ans'_{i}` denote another maximum element from array `A[0:i-1]`.

Then from induction hypothsis, `ans_{k} = ans'_{k}`

Now, for the sake of contradiction, assume `ans_{k+1} < ans'_{k+1}`

Now, how should I proceed to show this contradiction ?

Any suggestion? Should I change this approach ?

Comment: You can tell it without contradictions: so from you induction step you have ans' as a maximum from 0 to $k-1$, then it is greater or equal all elements from 0 to $i-1$, when you look at the ans which is the maximum from 0 to $k$, it is max of two elements then greater or equal than these two elements then greater or equal of all elements up to index $k$ so induction step done and you proved for all $k$.

Comment: can you show this contradiction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tip**: It's usually easy to proof by contradiction. Ignore the rest if you liked the suggestion.

Suppose you found some **ans** using your algorithm and **ans** is not the biggest.

If it's not the biggest, it means at some point, your **ans** was compared to a value **X** that's bigger than **ans** and **max(ans, X)** returned you ans.

Since **max** returns only the maximum value and **X** is bigger than **ans**, it's a contradiction.

---

By induction in the size **n** of the array, it's quite easy:

Base case: **n = 1**

- the algorithm will run and return the only element who is also the biggest [OK]

Hypohtesis: The algorithm works for any **n**

Inductive Step: It works for **n+1**

- Let's say you runned the first **n** elements of the array and you have your **ans**.
- Now you will just compare **ans** with the last element and you will return the biggest.
- As **ans** was the biggest from the first **n** elements (by hypothesis, we can find the biggest between **n** elements) and **ans** will be the maximum between **ans** and the last element, **ans** will be the maximum of the full array. [OK]

hope it helps.